# Hide/Encrypt WCF Client End Points in app.config

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, encryption

I have made a WPF application, and i am using multiple WCF services(deployed on remote server) in it. Currently all client configurations(**end points**) are given in app.config. If i open App.exe file (File Type: XML Configuration File) in notepad then i can see all configurations (**end points**) there.
What i want is that i want to hide that configurations so that end user can't see my configuration details (especially Address attribute).

Does Somebody know how to secure/hide my **WCF end point**? Either i need to use some tool to encrypt app.config file or i need to write client end points in code (if yes then how) ?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dtkwfdky.aspx you can encrypt your app.config, but what's the purpose of "hiding" them from users. Do you mean system adminstrators? normal users would not be able to access your config files

Comment: It a bit of the same question as the comment above: why do you want to? It doesn't have any advantages to hide the endpoint, as you can retrieve the call to the endpoint eventually via Fiddler.

Comment: Purpose of hiding is to avoid spamming and possible chances of miss use.

Comment: As Pazcal said. You *can't* hide the endpoint. If your enemy wants to discover it, they will, simply by looking at the network traffic. You probably need to secure your endpoint from whatever threats you think it faces.

Comment: OK, is there any way that i can move these end points to C# Code instead config file?

Answer (score 3):

If you're worried about divulging your endpoint address, you're doing security wrong.  It sounds like what you need is--at minimum--to authenticate your WCF service properly.

I recommend starting with the [WCF Security documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff405740.aspx).

Comment: Yes, you are right, we can track it using fiddler web debugger. But it was requirement from seniors so i have implemented this successfully in C# code.